join_where with starts_with in polars
I have two data frames,
df = pl.DataFrame({'url': ['https//abc.com', 'https//abcd.com', 'https//abcd.com/aaa', 'https//abc.com/abcd']})


conditions_df = pl.DataFrame({'url': ['https//abc.com', 'https//abcd.com', 'https//abcd.com/aaa', 'https//abc.com/aaa'], 'category': [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d']]})

now I want a df, for assigning categories to the first df based on first match for the url starts with in second df, that is the output should be,



url
category




https//abc.com
['a']


https//abcd.com
['b']


https//abcd.com/aaa
['b'] - this one starts with https//abcd.com, that is the first match


https//abc.com/abcd
['a'] - this one starts with https//abc.com, that is the first match



current code which works is like this,
def add_category_column(df: pl.DataFrame, conditions_df) -> pl.DataFrame:
    
    # Initialize the category column with empty lists
    df = df.with_columns(pl.Series("category", [[] for _ in range(len(df))], dtype=pl.List(pl.String)))
    
    # Apply the conditions to populate the category column
    for row in conditions_df.iter_rows():
        url_start, category = row
        df = df.with_columns(
            pl.when(
                (pl.col("url").str.starts_with(url_start)) & (pl.col("category").list.len() == 0)
            )
            .then(pl.lit(category))
            .otherwise(pl.col("category"))
            .alias("category")
        )
    
    return df

but is there a way to achieve the same without using for loops, could we use join_where here, but in my attempts join_where does not work for starts_with

Would you be able to elaborate on what "first match" means in your scenario? Is it the first arbitrary match? the shortest substring? the first row based on how they are ordered in your example?

The first row based on how they are ordered

I would expect pl.DataFrame.join_where() to work, but apparently it doesn't allow pl.Expr.str.starts_with() condition yet - I get only 1 binary comparison allowed as join condition error.
So you can use pl.DataFrame.join() and pl.DataFrame.filter() instead:
(
    df
    .join(conditions_df, how="cross")
    .filter(pl.col("url").str.starts_with(pl.col("url_right")))
    .sort("url")
    .group_by("url", maintain_order=True)
    .agg(pl.col.category.first())
)

shape: (4, 2)
┌─────────────────────┬───────────┐
│ url                 ┆ category  │
│ ---                 ┆ ---       │
│ str                 ┆ list[str] │
╞═════════════════════╪═══════════╡
│ https//abc.com      ┆ ["a"]     │
│ https//abc.com/abcd ┆ ["a"]     │
│ https//abcd.com     ┆ ["b"]     │
│ https//abcd.com/aaa ┆ ["b"]     │
└─────────────────────┴───────────┘

You can also use DuckDB integration with Polars and use lateral join:
import duckdb

duckdb.sql("""
    select
        d.url,
        c.category
    from df as d,
        lateral (
            select c.category
            from conditions_df as c
            where
                starts_with(d.url, c.url)
            limit 1
        ) as c
""")

┌─────────────────────┬───────────┐
│         url         │ category  │
│       varchar       │ varchar[] │
├─────────────────────┼───────────┤
│ https//abc.com      │ [a]       │
│ https//abc.com/abcd │ [a]       │
│ https//abcd.com/aaa │ [b]       │
│ https//abcd.com     │ [b]       │
└─────────────────────┴───────────┘

however, you have to be careful cause in standard SQL specification row collections are unordered, so I'd not do that in production without adding explicit order by clause into lateral part.

Unfortunately it does not look like it at the moment. I've just made this issue on the Polars issue tracker requesting it.
Here's a slight variation on @roman's answer that prepares a row index before the join.
(
    df.join(conditions_df.with_row_index(), how="cross")
    .filter(pl.col("url").str.starts_with(pl.col("url_right")))
    # pick only the first match based on lowest row number
    # needs to happen after the starts with filter
    .filter(pl.col("index") == pl.col("index").min().over("url"))
    .select("url", "category")
)

Or if you have bigger data or performance issues, this solution via DuckDB will do a join on starts_with (Polars SQL doesn't look to support it yet)
sql = """
select df.url, c.category
from df
inner join (select *, row_number() over() as index from conditions_df) as c
on starts_with(df.url, c.url)
-- pick only the first match based on lowest row number
-- this happens after the join is already done
qualify index = min(index) over(partition by df.url)
"""
duckdb.query(sql).pl()


It is possible to find the matches by doing a horizontal concat first - instead of an initial join.
It requires some more manual steps - but has given me the fastest results when dealing with larger inputs, so may be of interest.
(df.with_row_index()
   .join(
       pl.concat(
           [
               df.with_row_index(), 
               conditions_df.rename({"url": "condition_url"}).drop("category")
           ],
           how = "horizontal"
       )
       .with_columns(
           pl.col.url.str.extract_many(pl.col.condition_url, overlapping=True)
             .alias("condition_url")
       )
       .explode("condition_url")
       .filter(pl.col.url.str.starts_with(pl.col.condition_url))
       .group_by("index")
       .agg(pl.col.condition_url.first())
       .join(
           conditions_df.rename({"url": "condition_url"}),
           on = "condition_url"
       ),
       on = "index",
       how = "left"
  )
)

shape: (5, 4)
┌───────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────┬───────────┐
│ index ┆ url                 ┆ condition_url   ┆ category  │
│ ---   ┆ ---                 ┆ ---             ┆ ---       │
│ u32   ┆ str                 ┆ str             ┆ list[str] │
╞═══════╪═════════════════════╪═════════════════╪═══════════╡
│ 0     ┆ https//abc.com      ┆ https//abc.com  ┆ ["a"]     │
│ 1     ┆ https//abcd.com     ┆ https//abcd.com ┆ ["b"]     │
│ 2     ┆ https//abcd.com/aaa ┆ https//abcd.com ┆ ["b"]     │
│ 3     ┆ https//abc.com/abcd ┆ https//abc.com  ┆ ["a"]     │
│ 4     ┆ nomatch             ┆ null            ┆ null      │
└───────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────┴───────────┘

Explanation
We horizontally .concat() the frames and use .str.extract_many() to get a list of all substring matches which we explode into rows.
possible_matches = (
    pl.concat(
        [
            df.with_row_index(), 
            conditions_df.rename({"url": "condition_url"}).drop("category")
        ],
        how = "horizontal"
    )
    .with_columns(
        pl.col.url.str.extract_many(pl.col.condition_url, overlapping=True)
          .alias("condition_url")
    )
    .explode("condition_url")
)

shape: (6, 3)
┌───────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ index ┆ url                 ┆ condition_url       │
│ ---   ┆ ---                 ┆ ---                 │
│ u32   ┆ str                 ┆ str                 │
╞═══════╪═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 0     ┆ https//abc.com      ┆ https//abc.com      │
│ 1     ┆ https//abcd.com     ┆ https//abcd.com     │
│ 2     ┆ https//abcd.com/aaa ┆ https//abcd.com     │
│ 2     ┆ https//abcd.com/aaa ┆ https//abcd.com/aaa │
│ 3     ┆ https//abc.com/abcd ┆ https//abc.com      │
│ 4     ┆ nomatch             ┆ null                │
└───────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘

We then apply the starts_with filter and first constraint.
matches = (
    possible_matches
     .filter(pl.col.url.str.starts_with(pl.col.condition_url))
     .group_by("index")
     .agg(pl.col.condition_url.first())
)

shape: (4, 2)
┌───────┬─────────────────┐
│ index ┆ condition_url   │
│ ---   ┆ ---             │
│ u32   ┆ str             │
╞═══════╪═════════════════╡
│ 0     ┆ https//abc.com  │
│ 1     ┆ https//abcd.com │
│ 2     ┆ https//abcd.com │
│ 3     ┆ https//abc.com  │
└───────┴─────────────────┘

A .join() is used to get the corresponding category.
matches.join(
    conditions_df.rename({"url": "condition_url"}), 
    on = "condition_url"
)

shape: (4, 3)
┌───────┬─────────────────┬───────────┐
│ index ┆ condition_url   ┆ category  │
│ ---   ┆ ---             ┆ ---       │
│ u32   ┆ str             ┆ list[str] │
╞═══════╪═════════════════╪═══════════╡
│ 0     ┆ https//abc.com  ┆ ["a"]     │
│ 3     ┆ https//abc.com  ┆ ["a"]     │
│ 1     ┆ https//abcd.com ┆ ["b"]     │
│ 2     ┆ https//abcd.com ┆ ["b"]     │
└───────┴─────────────────┴───────────┘

And a final .join() is used to add the matching rows back to the original frame based on their index.
